# How do I clear the console using JavaScript In Codehs.com?

Tags: javascript

I tried to use clear.console(). But that didn't work. So I looked in the documentation. And there is NOTHING in the documentation that you can use to clear the console. The only thing I found online for Codehs.com specifically, uses octal codes but it was in Java. Not Javascript. But I can't use any octal codes anyway since there is nothing in the documentation about using sloppy mode! I know Codehs is a crappy compiler but it's the one my school uses so I can't change it.

Comment: That is not JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Please see: Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?. Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”? –

Comment: `clear.console()` should be `console.clear()`

Comment: The error message about strict mode makes no sense. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for a description of the changes that strict mode makes, and there's nothing about color codes.

Comment: There's no way to enable sloppy mode, as it's the default. You get it by not putting `"use strict"` at the beginning of the code. If Codehs.com forces that, there's no way to undo it.

Comment: console.clear() Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is in [the documentation](https://static1.codehs.com/gulp/1edc730c184f9950e19e21d320171c1b14507618/jsdoc/chs-js-lib/CodeHSConsole.html), the method is `clear()`

```js
println("Hello world");
clear();
println("Adios world");
```

At the top of the "Docs" tab it says "Want more? See our [full documentation!](https://static1.codehs.com/gulp/1edc730c184f9950e19e21d320171c1b14507618/jsdoc/chs-js-lib/index.html)"

You can try it here: https://codehs.com/sandbox/samathingamajig/clear